# MySQL favorite items from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, entity-relationship

What is the most efficient way to store favorites when there are multiple tables to choose from.

For example: You have a User (ID, Name, ...), Food (ID, calories, ...), Cocktails (ID, Alcoholic, ...) and Sweets (ID, Name, ...), the user can favorite multiple elements from these tables. What would be the best way to solve this.

My thought would be to create a many-to-many relation, where i have the user in a relation with every table above (User-Food, User-Cocktails, User-Sweets) or a favorite table where i have the foreign keys for all of the tables mentioned above.

The latter wouldn't be the optimal solution i guess.

Comment: What would be wrong with storing all items in a single table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a `favorite` table with a single column for all item types.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE favorite
                (user integer,
                 item integer,
                 item_type varchar(256),
                 PRIMARY KEY (user,
                              item,
                              item_type),
                 FOREIGN KEY (user)
                             REFERENCES user
                                        (id));
   ```

   `item` is the ID from the respective table (`food`, `cocktail` or `sweet`).

   `item_type` is needed to ensure uniqueness as `item` can be equal for two items of different types. It's e.g. the table name (`'food'`, `'cocktail'` or `'sweet'`). It can also act as a helper column to designate the type of the item `item` points to.

   Advantages:

   - Does not need a schema change, when a new item type is introduced.
   - No extra logic is needed for adding and removing favorites, one row per favorite -- simple.

   Disadvantages:

   - You can't add a foreign key constraint on `item` as it's referencing different tables per row. You'd have to implement a trigger to ensure referential integrity.
2. Create a `favorite` table with a column for each item type.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE favorite
                (id integer
                    AUTO_INCREMENT,
                 user integer,
                 food integer,
                 cocktail integer,
                 sweet integer,
                 PRIMARY KEY (id),
                 FOREIGN KEY (food)
                             REFERENCES food
                                        (id),
                 FOREIGN KEY (cocktail)
                             REFERENCES cocktail
                                        (id),
                 FOREIGN KEY (sweet)
                             REFERENCES sweet
                                        (id),
                 UNIQUE (user,
                         food),
                 UNIQUE (user,
                         cocktail),
                 UNIQUE (user,
                         sweet));
   ```

   Advantages:

   - Foreign key constraints can be used.

   Disadvantages:

   - Needs a schema change, when a new item type is introduced.
   - It gets a little complicated if users can have an arbitrary number of favorites of each item type. Then there need to be more rows for a user. I.e., when a new favorite is added, one has to check if an existing row can be updated, where the respective column of the favorite type is null, or if a new row needs to be inserted, because the respective column is already not null in all rows for the user. When removing a favourite an all `NULL`s row should probably deleted. This needs extra logic in the application or has to be encapsulated in a trigger or procedure.

   Might be a good choice if users can only have one favorite per item type though.
3. Introduce a common `item` table and let the different item tables reference that common table. The favourites table will reference only the common table.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE item
                (id integer
                    AUTO_INCREMENT,
                 PRIMARY KEY (id));

   INSERT INTO item
               SELECT NULL
                      FROM food
               UNION ALL
               SELECT NULL
                      FROM cocktail
               UNION ALL
               SELECT NULL
                      FROM sweet;

   ALTER TABLE food
               ADD (item integer,
                    FOREIGN KEY (item)
                                REFERENCES item
                                          (id));
   ALTER TABLE cocktail
               ADD (item integer,
                    FOREIGN KEY (item)
                                REFERENCES item
                                          (id));
   ALTER TABLE sweet
               ADD (item integer,
                    FOREIGN KEY (item)
                                REFERENCES item
                                          (id));

   UPDATE food
          SET item = (SELECT count(*)
                             FROM food s
                             WHERE s.id <= food.id);
   UPDATE cocktail
          SET item = (SELECT count(*)
                             FROM cocktail s
                             WHERE s.id <= food.id)
                     + (SELECT count(*)
                               FROM food);
   UPDATE sweet
          SET item = (SELECT count(*)
                             FROM sweet s
                             WHERE s.id <= food.id)
                     + (SELECT count(*)
                               FROM food)
                     + (SELECT count(*)
                               FROM cocktail);

   ALTER TABLE food
               MODIFY item integer
                           NOT NULL;
   ALTER TABLE cocktail
               MODIFY item integer
                           NOT NULL;
   ALTER TABLE sweet
               MODIFY item integer
                           NOT NULL;

   CREATE TABLE favorite
                (user integer,
                 item integer,
                 PRIMARY KEY (user,
                              item),
                 FOREIGN KEY (user)
                             REFERENCES user
                                        (id),
                 FOREIGN KEY (item)
                             REFERENCES item
                                        (id));
   ```

   Optionally you can add a helper column in `item` to designate the item type of `id`. Also optionally you can drop `id` from the different item tables (`food`, `cocktail` or `sweet`) and use `item` as primary key instead.

   Advantages:

   - Does not need a schema change, when a new item type is introduced.
   - Foreign key constraints can be used.
   - No extra logic is needed for adding and removing favorites, one row per favorite -- simple.

   Disadvantages:

   - It's a little tricky to introduce.
   - Might require to change the existing application logic as an item of any type now needs an additional insert into `item` when being created. Can alternatively handled by some trigger -- actually it just needs to create a new `item.id` to satisfy the foreign key constraint in the respective item table (`food`, `cocktail` or `sweet`), so it's fairly simple.

   Overall possibly the "cleanest" solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the third possibility is the best, but what would be the query if I want to get all favourites, with the data sets of all tables.
For example. a User has favorite foods,cocktails and sweets and we want all attribute values for foods, cocktails and sweets.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two options:

```
create table favorites (
    favoritesId int auto_increment primary key,
    userId,
    which varchar(255),
    id int,
    foreign key (userId) references users(userId)
);
```

This is short, concise and lets you add new entities.

Alternatively, you can list each one separately:

```
create table favorites (
    favoritesId int auto_increment primary key,
    foodId int,
    cocktailsId int,
    . . .
    foreign key (userId) references users(userId),
    foreign key (foodId) references foods(foodId),
    foreign key (cocktailsId) references cocktails(cocktailsId),
    . . .
);
```

This is less concise but it does allow you to add explicit foreign key references.  It also makes it easy to represent multiple favorites on a single row, if that is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `Favorite` table
and add `FOREIGN KEY` from another four table

it looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE User (`ID` int not null, `Name` varchar(5)) ;
INSERT INTO User (`ID`, `Name`) 
  VALUES (1, 'Jogn'), (2, 'Henry') ; 

CREATE TABLE Food (`ID` int, `calories` int) ; 
INSERT INTO Food (`ID`, `calories`) 
  VALUES (1, 123), (2, 456) ; 

CREATE TABLE Cocktails (`ID` int, `Alcoholic` int) ; 
INSERT INTO Cocktails (`ID`, `Alcoholic`) 
  VALUES (1, 30), (2, 40) ; 

CREATE TABLE Sweets (`ID` int, `Name` varchar(5)) ; 
INSERT INTO Sweets (`ID`, `Name`) 
  VALUES (1, 'candy'), (2, 'cake') ;


CREATE TABLE Favorite
    (`ID` int
     , `UserID` int not null
     , `FoodID` int 
     , `CocktailsID` int
     , `SweetsID` int
    )
;

ALTER TABLE `User` ADD CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);
ALTER TABLE `Food` ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Food PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);
ALTER TABLE `Cocktails` ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Cocktails PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);
ALTER TABLE `Sweets` ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Sweets PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `Favorite` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Favorite_User
  FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `User`(`ID`); 
ALTER TABLE `Favorite` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Favorite_Food
  FOREIGN KEY (`FoodID`) REFERENCES `Food`(`ID`); 
ALTER TABLE `Favorite` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Favorite_Cocktails
  FOREIGN KEY (`CocktailsID`) REFERENCES `Cocktails`(`ID`); 
ALTER TABLE `Favorite` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Sweetss
  FOREIGN KEY (`SweetsID`) REFERENCES `Sweets`(`ID`);   

INSERT INTO Favorite 
    (`ID`, `UserID`, `FoodID`, `CocktailsID`, `SweetsID`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '1', NULL, NULL),
    (2, 2, NULL, '2', NULL),
    (3, 1, NULL, NULL, '1')
;
```

when i insert not exists value for Sweets

```
INSERT INTO Favorite 
    (`ID`, `UserID`, `FoodID`, `CocktailsID`, `SweetsID`)
VALUES
    (3, 1, NULL, NULL, 4)
;
```

it'll throw exception

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_9_1a5d3f`.`favorite`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Sweetss` FOREIGN KEY (`SweetsID`) REFERENCES `sweets` (`ID`))
```

---

and you can query them by this SQL script (maybe create a view):

```
select
  T1.ID FavoriteID,
  T1.`UserID`,
  case when T2.ID is not null then 'Food'
    when T3.ID is not null then 'Cocktails'
    when T4.ID is not null then 'Sweets'
  end type,
  COALESCE(T2.ID,T3.ID,T4.ID) ID  
from Favorite T1
left join Food T2 on T1.`FoodID` = T2.`ID`
left join Cocktails T3 on T1.`CocktailsID` = T3.`ID`
left join Sweets T4 on T1.`SweetsID` = T4.`ID`

| FavoriteID | UserID |      type | ID |
|------------|--------|-----------|----|
|          1 |      1 |      Food |  1 |
|          2 |      2 | Cocktails |  2 |
|          3 |      1 |    Sweets |  1 |
```

---

If you want test : [SQL Fiddle Test Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4d9ae/5/0)